# Proving identity for the covariant derivative of $df$

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that $f$ is a vector field in and $x$ is a vector in a general manifold $M$, then I need to show that the covariant derivative of the one form $df$ is given by

$\nabla_x(df)=d(xf)$.

Comment: What is the definition of covariant derivative of a one-form?

Comment: And what's the definition of $df$ when $f$ is a vector field? The operator $d$ applies to functions and differential forms, not to vector fields.

Comment: @JackLee. $df$ represents a $1-$form, so $df=\sum_j{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j}$.

Comment: Yeah but if $\text{d}f$ is a 1-form then $f$ is a 0-form or in other words a scalar function.